# Updating Params attributes in controller methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I have an object that is behaving very strangely in my rails application.

2 of my controller methods are relevant.

```
  def index
    @user_vacation_days = UserVacationDay.all
  end
```

Real simple.

```
  def create 

    params[:user_vacation_day][:user_id] = current_user.id 
    params[:user_vacation_day][:user] = current_user  # supplementary       

    @user_vacation_day = UserVacationDay.create(params[:user_vacation_day]) #user_vacation_day
    @user_vacation_day.update_attributes(user: current_user)

    if @user_vacation_day.persisted?
        flash[:notice] = "Request Sent"
        redirect_to dashboard_index_path
      #UserVacationDayMailer.request_vacation_days(@user_vacation_day.id).deliver

    else
        flash[:notice] = "Something went wrong, please try again"
        render :new
    end

  end
```

This one is being tricky. The lines

```
params[:user_vacation_day][:user_id] = current_user.id 
params[:user_vacation_day][:user] = current_user
```

are misbehaving. When I go into my rails console, and type

```
UserVacationDay.all
```

I get

```
[#<UserVacationDay id: 34, user: nil, description: "work!", response: nil, response_description: "placeholder", created_at: "2013-07-18 15:46:07", updated_at: "2013-07-18 16:29:24", state: "denied", number_of_days_off_requested: 100, user_id: 1>]
```

Notice how user is nil. It shouldn't be, and I don't understand why. The thing that's driving me crazy is my index form. It displays all of the vacation day requests. The following segment actually works in the browser, and submits and everything without noticeable errors. Here it is:

```
- @user_vacation_days.each do |u|
  #{u.user.full_name} has requested #{u.number_of_days_off_requested} vacation days
  %br
  "#{u.description}"
  %br
  .btn-group
    %button.btn.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle
      = link_to "Respond", edit_user_vacation_day_path(u)
```

It lets me call u.user.full_name, which is the same as calling @user_vacation_day.user.full_name.

I don't know why this is happening in the index method, but not the create method. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have both `user` and `user_id`? If `UserVacationDay belongs_to :user`, I'm pretty sure rails is going to be fairly confused by your `user` and `user_id` attributes. Usually, if you do `@user_vacation_day.user = current_user`, that will set `user_id` to that of `current_user`.

Comment: I think you're right, I'd like to just have user_id. The problem is, I don't know how to get the user object from the user_id. Rails console simply returns the user id number

Comment: If you remove the `user` attribute from your model and set up a `belongs_to` association (like I mentioned above), doing `@user_vacation_day.user` will return the `User` object, and not just the id.

Comment: Ah. Well neat, I do have the belongs_to association. I'll go get rid of that pesky user now. Thanks a ton man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to implement your `create` action may be this:

```
def create 
  @user_vacation_day = UserVacationDay.new(params[:user_vacation_day])
  @user_vacation_day.user = current_user

  if @user_vacation_day.save
    flash[:notice] = "Request Sent"
    redirect_to dashboard_index_path
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Something went wrong, please try again"
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: You are using .new instead of .create. Will this be correct? I apologize, I am fairly new to rails, and I thought that create is the method to actually build an object and add it to the database

Comment: `new` creates the object but doesn't yet save it to the database. You can then set the `user` parameter and save it with `@user_vacation_day.save`. This makes the action only send one INSERT statement to the database, and is generally how a `create` action is implemented in Rails.